# how to find cpu cache size for a x86 processor

Tags: caching, assembly, x86

I want to find cpu cache size of L1 or L2 caches using x86 assembly language. I heard cpuid and MSR registers have system specific data. Can some one help me how can I get sizes please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a minimal example of how you'd go about finding it out using the **CPUID** instruction:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define cpuid(id) __asm__( "cpuid" : "=a"(eax), "=b"(ebx), "=c"(ecx), "=d"(edx) : "a"(id), "b"(0), "c"(0), "d"(0))
#define b(val, base, end) ((val << (__WORDSIZE-end-1)) >> (__WORDSIZE-end+base-1))

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        unsigned long eax, ebx, ecx, edx;

        cpuid(0);
        printf("identification: \"%.4s%.4s%.4s\"\n", (char *)&ebx, (char *)&edx, (char *)&ecx);

        printf("cpu information:\n");

        cpuid(1);
        printf(" family %ld model %ld stepping %ld efamily %ld emodel %ld\n",
                        b(eax, 8, 11), b(eax, 4, 7), b(eax, 0, 3), b(eax, 20, 27), b(eax, 16, 19));
        printf(" brand %ld cflush sz %ld*8 nproc %ld apicid %ld\n",
                        b(ebx, 0, 7), b(ebx, 8, 15), b(ebx, 16, 23), b(ebx, 24, 31));

        cpuid(0x80000006);
        printf("L1 cache size (per core): %ld KB\n", b(ecx, 16, 31));

        return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**CPUID**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) instruction. If you set the EAX register to certain values, you can get the informations you want in the EAX, EBX, ECX and EDX registers.

You can have more informations in [this guide](http://support.amd.com/us/Processor_TechDocs/25481.pdf) from AMD.

Answer (score 0):

As Soravux suggests, the `CPUID` intruction is what you'll want to look at. (You might want to have a look at `CPUID` in e.g. the Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 2A, [here](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/)).

The functions you'll probably be most interested in are: `CPUID.EAX=02h` and/or `CPUID.EAX=04h` (depending on your exact needs). These functions provide quite a lot of output, so I won't go through any details here, but Intel's and AMD's manuals should contain all you need.